# Mariadb won't start Can't open the mysql.plugin table

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

today I started to get this issue on my mariadb server

> 101126 10:29:53 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run
>   mysql_upgrade to create it.

Command *mysql_upgrade* didn't ed because the mysql server was stopped because of the error, so reading around the web I found this command as a possible soluton to the issue

> myisamchk –check /var/lib/mysql/*/*.MYI

So I ran it, but now, I'm getting this error:

```
160818 23:14:51 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160818 23:14:51 [ERROR] Aborting
160818 23:14:51 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

What can I do to get my server up and running again?

Thanks!

```
Package: mariadb-server (10.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
Ubuntu server 16.04 x64
```

Comment: The part between it telling you to run a command and you running an entirely different command doesn't make sense, some words missing?  You need to run the upgrade to create the missing tables.  Myisamchk checks existing tables, it's not going to create a missing one for you...

Comment: read first my friend "Command mysql_upgrade didn't worked because the mysql server was stopped because of the error"

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems to be a package issue, because I restored my server system image to a past time and upgraded everything and mariadb works just fine...so I will report a bug for this, because after upgrade it complaintt this tables missing innodb_index_stats and innodb_table_stats, so I tried mysql_upgrade -uroot -p that failed the first time, then ran it again and said "This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 10.0.25-MariaDB..." and for the third time with the --force worked ok...really weird!